# Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 upgrade: power save blacks screen for 5 minutes

Tags: 14.04, 13.10, upgrade

I am facing a problem when logging into Ubuntu 14.04 since I upgraded it from 13.1. In details, when I log on, the screen goes off and a power save message is displayed in green color and I have to wait at least 5 minutes for the screen to recover.

I tried different things but no success.

Please I am in urgent need for your help as I have this problem on 15 PCs in our lab at the university.

Comment: What did you try already? What hardware are you running on? (PC and monitor) Are all machines identical?

Comment: Hi Fabby, all PCs are Lenovo with the following specifications:

The ram is: 7.6 GiB

Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8 

The graphic card: Intel® Ivybridge Desktop

  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0

Comment: And what did you try already?  Did it include turning off all power management?  (I'm trying to look for a quick fix)

Comment: I went to system settings > brightness > untick the “Dim  …......” >change the “turn off when …...” to Never

Also, Opened a terminal and typed 
sudo apt-get install genome-tweaks-tools
then 
genome-tweaks-tools

Then went to Power>and changed any suspend to nothing

Comment: But how can I switch the power management off???

Comment: In the following order: on the monitor, go into the monitor settings and turn off all power management features.  On 1 (one) computer, reboot and go into the BIOS and turn off all power management settings, in Ubuntu execute:
`cat /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/* > /tmp/power-d.txt` and paste it in http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and report back with the http-link...

Comment: Hi Fabby, I have posted the text file on http://paste.ubuntu.com/9422487/

Comment: What did turning off the monitor and BIOS Power Management do?

Comment: The power management was disabled using the BIOS

Comment: Regarding the monitor, I went to system settings, display, brightness, appearance, power and double checked that every thing related to power saving is disabled

Comment: I think I've got enough info...  Next will be an answer.  If that doesn't help you'll update your question and I'll update my answer...  ;)  The answer will (off course) contain some duplicates from our conversation here, so you can safely ignore those: these are for people running into the same problem as you in the future...

Answer (score 0):

As your problem is power-savings related, please follow these steps:

1. Go to the monitor settings and turn off anything that reeks of 'sleep', 'power management' etc
2. Go into the BIOS of your machine and turn off power management there
3. As all of these machines are *desktops*, run the following commands one by one:

   ```
   sudo pm-powersave false
   sudo apt-get remove gnome-power-manager
   sudo apt-get remove pm-utils
   sudo apt-get remove acpi-support
   ```
4. Reboot

Comment: It worked for the first computer but for others.

Comment: I have pasted the text file for the computer that did not work  http://paste.ubuntu.com/9437232/  as You may be able to compare the two posts please

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say it worked for one computer 9the one I have sent you posted its details). did not worked for others. I have posted the details of one of the computers that did not work on paste.ubuntu.com/9437232

Comment: Did you try re-installing the utilities on the computer it didn't work on and then copying the files from the working computer to the non-working computer and then running it again?

Comment: I have copied the pm-utils folder from the working computer and the non working computer and unfortunately did not work.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas...

Comment: How many computers did it work on?

Comment: After I sent you the last comment, I tried the following on the non working computer ( went to etc/pm/sleep.d)  and changed it to sleep_old.d to prevent the sleep from excuting. and it worked. Unfortunately, I repeated the same thin on the third computer but did not work. Not sure what is wrong

Comment: after performing 'sudo apt-get remove pm-utils' i should not see the pm-utils in usr/lib but i was able to see this folder there. So I also tried to modify the name of pm-utils to pm-utils_old on the third computer that did not work with all previous options. again it did not work.

Comment: One more thing, if I restart the computer and select ubuntu-recovery 13.1 ..... on boot, things go fine and no power save mode at all. But when I restart it again and select ubuntu 14.04, the same problem happens

Comment: And you didn't forget to also update the monitor and BIOS settings, did you? (Just asking...)

Comment: I made sure all settings related to power are disabled. Regarding the BIOS, by holding F1 on boot, and going to the Power tab, I found it disabled by default.

Comment: I'm all out of ideas...  Do you want me to delete my answer and upvote your question so it attracts more attention?

Comment: I am new to this forum. If this attracts more answers then please do so and many many thanks for such great help. Ali

Comment: I've upvoted your question and I'll leave mine in so the other people can see what we've already tried.  @Moderator: please move this extended discussion into the chat room as it doesn't provide any helpful feed-back to the next person looking at this question! (and I'm too low on the foodchain to do this myself as the OP has rep 1 only)